# Deleting the row from table 2 that exist in table 1 and add these extra rows to table1

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I wrote this query. I want to get the empty data that is not in the first dataset.

First query return 34 user 
Second query return 43 user 
I need to take the extra 10 users and add them to first

```
select projects_users_duration.user_id,
       projects_users_duration.engineer_name,
       COALESCE(sum(projects_users_duration.duration) FILTER ( WHERE projects_users_duration.project_type = 1 ), 0) as billed,
       COALESCE(sum(projects_users_duration.duration) FILTER ( WHERE projects_users_duration.project_type != 1 ), 0) as un_billed
    from
(select users_in_team.user_id, users_in_team.engineer_name, tt.month, tt.year, t.duration,
       (select up.project_type_id from users_project up where id = tt.project_id) as project_type
from (select uu.id as user_id, pgp_sym_decrypt(uu.name, '1234') as engineer_name
      from users_team_members as utm
               left join users_user uu on uu.id = utm.user_id
      where utm.team_id in (1, 2)) as users_in_team
         left join timetracker_timesheet tt on users_in_team.user_id = tt.user_id
         left join timetracker_timesheetentry t on tt.id = t.timesheet_id
where tt.month in (1)
  and tt.year = 2021
  and tt.status = 'approved') as projects_users_duration
group by projects_users_duration.user_id, projects_users_duration.engineer_name
```

```
select uu.id as user_id, pgp_sym_decrypt(uu.name, '1234') as engineer_name, 0 as billed, 0 as un_billed
      from users_team_members as utm
               left join users_user uu on uu.id = utm.user_id
      where utm.team_id in (1, 2)
```

The first dataset should include the empty data as well, but I think it's because of where clause.

Answer (score 0):

**To get all the rows from second query which are not available in first query:**

```
with cte as(select projects_users_duration.user_id,
       projects_users_duration.engineer_name,
       COALESCE(sum(projects_users_duration.duration) FILTER ( WHERE projects_users_duration.project_type = 1 ), 0) as billed,
       COALESCE(sum(projects_users_duration.duration) FILTER ( WHERE projects_users_duration.project_type != 1 ), 0) as un_billed
    from
(select users_in_team.user_id, users_in_team.engineer_name, tt.month, tt.year, t.duration,
       (select up.project_type_id from users_project up where id = tt.project_id) as project_type
from (select uu.id as user_id, pgp_sym_decrypt(uu.name, '1234') as engineer_name
      from users_team_members as utm
               left join users_user uu on uu.id = utm.user_id
      where utm.team_id in (1, 2)) as users_in_team
         left join timetracker_timesheet tt on users_in_team.user_id = tt.user_id
         left join timetracker_timesheetentry t on tt.id = t.timesheet_id
where tt.month in (1)
  and tt.year = 2021
  and tt.status = 'approved') as projects_users_duration
group by projects_users_duration.user_id, projects_users_duration.engineer_name)

select uu.id as user_id, pgp_sym_decrypt(uu.name, '1234') as engineer_name, 0 as billed, 0 as un_billed
      from users_team_members as u
```

tm
left join users_user uu on uu.id = utm.user_id
where utm.team_id in (1, 2)
and uu.id not in (select user_id from cte)

Now you can insert those rows in any table and also delete them as you wish.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using with, thank you. But above approach give me extra from table 2 only.

Comment: It's great to know tgat ur problem has been resolved. best wishes

Answer (score 0):

```
with team_members as (
    select uu.id                                                as user_id,
           pgp_sym_decrypt(uu.name, '12345') as engineer_name,
           0                                                    as billed,
           0                                                    as un_billed,
           0                                                    as total
    from users_team_members as utm
             left join users_user uu on uu.id = utm.user_id
    where utm.team_id in (1, 2)
      and (uu.end_date is null or uu.end_date > now())
    group by uu.id
),
     individual_data as (
         select projects_users_duration.user_id,
                projects_users_duration.engineer_name,
                COALESCE(sum(projects_users_duration.duration)
                         FILTER ( WHERE projects_users_duration.project_type = 1 ), 0)
                                                      as billed,
                COALESCE(sum(projects_users_duration.duration)
                         FILTER ( WHERE projects_users_duration.project_type != 1 ), 0)
                                                      as unbilled,
                sum(projects_users_duration.duration) as total
         from (select users_in_team.user_id,
                      users_in_team.engineer_name,
                      tt.month,
                      tt.year,
                      t.duration,
                      (select up.project_type_id from users_project up where id = tt.project_id) as project_type
               from team_members as users_in_team
                        left join timetracker_timesheet tt on users_in_team.user_id = tt.user_id
                        left join timetracker_timesheetentry t on tt.id = t.timesheet_id
               where tt.month in (1, 2, 3)
                 and tt.year = 2021
                 and tt.status in ('approved')) as projects_users_duration
         group by projects_users_duration.user_id, projects_users_duration.engineer_name
     )

    (select *
     from team_members
     where user_id not in (select user_id from individual_data)
     union
     select *
     from individual_data) order by total desc
```